# Attempt to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, fstream

While running a thread I got this error. I have used a reference to
the fstream as an argument to the readFile function to avoid copy
constructor calling also. Still I got the same error, How?

```
void readFile(fstream& fileStream)
{    
    // some code
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fstream stream;  
    readFile(stream);   
    thread oddPrint(readFile, stream);
    oddPrint.join();     
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why error did you get?  The post does not include it or any useful code for us to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read reference about [thread constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/). In below line

```
thread oddPrint(readFile, stream);
```

while calling `thread` constructor `stream` object is passed by value, but `fstream` class doesn't have copy operations so you got the error. If you want to pass non-copyable objects as parameters you have to use `std::ref` or `std::cref` wrappers:

```
thread oddPrint(readFile, std::ref(stream));
```